# Connection between 2 components

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, angular2-routing

I am implementing an angular exemple. I have an input for search in navbar component and i want to display results of search in another component but i found problem how the second component will know the value that i put it in the search input text.
This my navbar.ts file :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RechercheService } from 

   '../../services/recherche/recherche.service';
 @Component({
     selector: 'navbar',
     templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
            })
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  name: string ;
  listUsers;
  constructor(){}

    ngOnInit() {

    }



search() { 
    let list = this.rechercheService.recherche();
    if(this.name.length>2) {    
        let searchText = (this.name).toLowerCase();
        this.listUsers= list.filter( it => {
          return it.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);           
    });
    if(this.listUsers.length>0){
      this.sidenav.open(); 
    }
    else {
      this.sidenav.close();
    }
    }
      console.log(this.listUsers); 
      this.name = "";

     }
   }
```

This my navbar.html:

```
<div  class="col-3">
        <div class="input-group mb-2">
            <span class="borderColor rounded-left text-center"  
        (click)="search()"><mat-icon class="blueIcon loupeIcon" 
      fontIcon="icon-search"></mat-icon></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control color" 
        placeholder="search" [(ngModel)]="name" >
            <button class="btn-al-blue rounded-right" type="submit" >more 

            creteria</button>   
        </div>

    </div>
```

I want to display the result of search in another component called second.
how can i do it ?

Comment: you can use a service for sharing data using subject

Comment: I used rechercheService that contain allusers but to filter results i should use an input text and how the second component will know the value puted in the input text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create shared service for the same

```
// Search Control
searchFilter = new Subject<any>();
searchFiltered = this.searchFilter.asObservable();
emitSearchFilter(value) {
    this.searchFilter.next(value);
}
```

emit from navbar component like

```
this.navbarService.emitSearchFilter('search keyword');
```

and subscribe to another component like

```
this.navbarService.searchFiltered.subscribe(value => {
    console.log(value);
  });
```

don't forget to unsubscribe on ngDestroy

Comment: this.rechercheService.emitSearchFilter is not a function